# 2HornSAT with exact cardinality?

Tags: complexity-theory, np-complete

Given a 2HornSAT problem. Its possible in linear time to find the minimum solution to the problem i.e. that has minimum number of variables set to 1 in the solution.

Now let us consider another variant of the problem:

Given a positive integer K, is there a solution to the 2HornSAT such that exactly K variables are set to 1?

Is this problem NP-Complete. I am struggling with its reduction but it seems this might be difficult.

Comment: Is 2HornSAT a conjunction of clauses where each clause is a conjunction of exactly one positive and one negative term?

Comment: Yes. Each clause has 2 literals - one positive and another negative. And there are N such clauses.

Comment: I can't exactly think of a full answer, but I suspect this is not NP-complete. Look at [the strongly connected components algorithm of 2SAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2-satisfiability#Strongly_connected_components). I think that in the last step you can do something more sophisticated than a simple topological sort to find a solution with $k$ true variables, perhaps with dynamic programming on $k$.

Comment: I am not sure (either way). " I think that in the last step you can do something more sophisticated than a simple topological sort to find a solution with kk true variables, perhaps with dynamic programming on kk." - Not sure how it can be achieved.

Comment: If each clause contains a negative literal, then you can set each variable to *false*, and that assignment is minimal and satisfying. Usually HornSAT means *at most* one negated literal per clause, not exactly one. That case may be more interesting.

Comment: I understand. But, I think the question is not regarding the minimal satisfying solution (as clarified in the first line itself). Its regarding exact cardinality  K rather than minimum K. Moreover, we can only consider only the case where 1 literal is false another is true (and exclude 'all  negative' horn clauses). It will work just fine.

Comment: Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). If your question has gone more than a week with no answers, you can raise a custom flag to ask that it be migrated.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question, even though it is on-topic, because it was [also posted on CSTheory.SE](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/38288/5038).